# Do I need to do more to earn Selfie hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

I answered my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27493471/554807).

But ... no selfie hat yet.   Do I need to do more?

OK ... the answer was "you need to have that answer upvoted" ... the answer has an upvote now, but still no selfie hat.   Does the question need to have a positive score too?!

Comment: The post needs to have a positive score.

Comment: You kids and your selfies. Next you'll be asking how to get a twerking hat.

Comment: Yeah - I was totally wondering about that! :)

Comment: I lost it at "Twerking hat"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Selfie hat requires the answer to be scored above zero, to prevent abuse. More information from [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer/245123#245123):

> ## Implicit quality requirements
>
> To prevent people from posting nonsense just to earn a hat, most hats that require creating content, especially questions and answers, have some requirements that may not be mentioned in the hat description. Generally this involves questions/answers having a positive score (i.e. getting at least one upvote), not being closed/deleted, etc. If the hat has an additional date requirement, it is okay if the upvote comes in after the time is already over, as long as the content was created during the time.

Comment: @Sompuperoo It looks like the question has to have been asked within the Winterbash period too. So ask and answer within the period, both having a score greater than zero.

Comment: The "question needs to be upvoted" part seems like it will make this hat hard to get. Usually when I answer my own question, it's because I asked about something obscure that no one was able to help with, and consequently my question gets 0 votes because few people read it.