# How many Scrooges are there on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I'd be interested (just out of curiosity about human nature) to know how many of our users have shouted *Bah Humbug!* and then clicked the "I Hate Hats" link to parry any attempt to infect them with festive spirit.

Could someone with the appropriate access take a peek?

(For the purposes of this question, I am prepared to assume, quite reasonably, I think, that everyone who clicks the link also shouts *Bah Humbug!* beforehand.)

---

UPDATE: perhaps the voting (+11/-13) on this question is giving a clue!

Comment: Quicklook: compare the 19 downvotes on the negatively stated [What is this hat system useful for?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280383/what-is-this-hat-system-useful-for) against the 314 *up*votes on the positive [Do we want hats?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats).

Comment: @Jongware 21 downvotes. It has 2 upvotes. The other has 342 upvotes and 28 people who hate hats.

Comment: I hate hats, mostly because of the all the stupid actions people take to earn them, like "Let's upvote every single question on the main page" (seen it happen twice so far), answering their own questions with "This is an answer for a hat", and all the "Why haven't I gotten this hat?!?" questions on Meta.  I like fun (contrary to comments here or popular opinion), but I hate hats as implemented.  Just give us a bunch of silly hats to pick from, or at least have the requirements be completely innocuous.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Downvote stupid question/answers like that. There are [implicit quality requirements](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280355/3156863) that mean bad content won't earn you a hat.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can hate a mullet as magnificent as the one they have here.

Comment: Please don't bump this question just to edit in updated vote numbers, that's simply annoying.

Comment: @l4mpi Good point, I'd forgotten it would bump it. I'll stop.

Comment: I dont' understand what it has to do with Scrooge. The hats are for free, and even if the weren't, you shouldn't judge people for not willing to spend even pennies on something that's actually of no practical use

Answer (score 6):

Probably not many, because Stack Overflow(-only) users that hate hats don't have to do anything. On Stack Overflow hats are off by default, you only see them if you explicitly say you like them either by clicking "I like hats" or by actually putting on a hat (on a different site).

Comment: Yes, I saw that written somewhere else. I can't make sense of it. I'm sure I didn't explicitly turn hats on... did I?!

Comment: Yep, you did. Precisely at 1:39:33 UTC on Monday :)

Comment: At 1:39am?! No wonder I don't remember!

Comment: You know, I'm a bit disappointed that my hat suggestion hasn't been taken up on - again. `Full Metal Jacket: cast 3000 close votes.` http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131902/138112

Comment: What is the story behind *your* hat, balpha? I can't find it on the official page.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ssshhhh, it's a secret!

Answer (score 5):

I'll admit, I hated hats last year. Mainly because I was new, and still trying to figure out how things work around here. So it just seemed like an annoyance and I didn't try to learn more about it.

This year however, I really love hats!

So I don't think many people really *hate* hats, they just don't understand them.

Answer (score 3):

Wait, you think I'm a humbug? Because I "clicked the *I Hate Hats*"?

No, it's the bloody cost of the tree, and pine needles every-bloody-where, and huge sodding turkey which tastes like Gandhi's old flip-flop, and overpriced presents for the kids who use them for less than a week, and girlfriend, and copious amounts of our good wine the parents drink leaving their *£2.99 for two* red vinegar behind when they leave in a cab intoxicated with our 10-quid-a-bottle M&S best.

And the fact we have to buy the dog a present, I mean does the dog really care?

Plus the cost of Christmas tree lights which cost more electricity, why do we bloody need them on *all* the sodding time?
I said to her, we should just get the kids to flick cigarette lighters to the tune of "This is the End" by the Doors, save us a fortune.

And don't get me started on the price of *Christmas crackers* which never bloody bang. They should call them *Christmas pfft-ers*.
And the stupid jokes which are worse than the ones my grandpa tells after 6 sherries, and the plastic cheap toys which you spin or touch once and fall apart.

And then she wants lights outside the house around the front door? What the ... sodding 'ell?
We can't even see them!! All that electricity for the neighbours to enjoy Christmas lights, sodd them! They can buy their own!!

Humbug? No, *free* hat's are great...

Comment: Umm... But these are free just find a few spammers and tell them to join.